# What is the difference between Mozilla and Firefox in SO browser statistics?

Tags: discussion, browsers

I am reading a post from https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/

```
What web browsers do Stack Overflow users use?
Firefox  44.1%
Internet Explorer  22.7%
Chrome  22.6%
Safari  7.4%
Opera  2.4%
Mozilla  0.5%
```

I am using **Mozilla Firefox** V3.6.13 on winXP.

Why the analysis report listed the two category *Firefox* and *Mozilla*?
Does Mozilla come from Linux system as another web brower?
:-)

Comment: Shot in the dark, but possibly Seamonkey, Camino, or *(cringe)* Netscape? They were/are all made by Mozilla at one point. Or possibly a malformed UA string confused Analytics?

Comment: I would like to see a more recent version of this table. Does anyone have a link to one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this huge [tree of browser lineage](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Timeline_of_web_browsers.svg): it should be apparent that there are browsers (SeaMonkey, Flock, Camino) other than Firefox based on the Gecko rendering engine. I'd assume they are grouped under Mozilla, as that's their common ancestor (as they mostly differ in the GUI, while the engine remains the same. Also, each separately would not register at all).

Comment: I hadn't seen that!! amazing :)